# Highlight line, even if there is a selection

Tags: visual-studio-code

I changed `settings.json`, so that the current line is easier to see (dark green background):

[image: highlight-one-line-in-vscode]

But this highlighting disappears as soon as there is a selection.

For example I select the word "editor", and now the dark green background is gone:

[image: highlight-in-vscode-gone]

How to highlight the current line (dark green background), even if there is a selection?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour. My take: This is either a bug (unintended behaviour), or by design (intended behaviour). I don't think you will find out which it is by asking here (you should ask the maintainers), and I don't think you can get what you want by asking here (you should ask the maintainers). I might be wrong, but I'd wager I'm right.

Answer (score 2):

I can also reproduce this behavior, I agree with the comment answer. But FWIW, this [highlight line extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cliffordfajardo.highlight-line-vscode) may do what you are looking for!

[image]

Comment: The plugin was uploaded once five years ago, and then there was no maintainance. My gut feeling tells me that I should avoid this plugin.

Comment: @guettli fair point, although I don't worry too much when it is something so simple/purely visual.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the setting

```
Editor: Render Line Highlight => all
```

to `all` will help you "some".  The line highlight in the **gutter** will remain even if something is selected in that line.  Other than an extension, it is probably the best you can do.

You can also tweak the line number color for a active line with this `colorCustomization`:

```
"editorLineNumber.activeForeground": "#fff",
```

[image: highlight line and number]